# Need regular expression. Any character number

Tags: regex, numbers

I need a Regular expression.

Any symbols (or letter?) or digits, but it must not contain only digits:

```
jhfj7484 - passes
3434jhfj - passes
jку343hj - passes
63728134 - does not pass
6372813t - passes
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: StackOverflow is an english based website thus I'm voting to close this question as "unclear".

Comment: The original "on hold" could be lifted now that the question is in English, but could then be put "on hold" immediately because the OP didn't show any attempt to solving the issue: *"Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work."*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, it is kind of you to translate this message, but what if the OP is not able to understand English?

Comment: @BartKiers We'll talk in PHP code `function solution()use('/^\D+$/'){}` :D

Comment: @BartKiers: she wrotes the title in english.

Comment: @BartKiers (s)he needs to move to another site, where people speak in language that OP knows, in that case.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, ah, didn't notice that!

Comment: @PLB,I'm not disputing that, but that didn't change the fact that the OP wouldn't have understood the English question (or the hint to go to another site :)). But as Casimir et Hippolyte pointed out, the title was written in English, so s/he must be able to understand the comments (and "on hold" reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this with a regex (assuming ASCII characters only):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

This only matches if there is at least one ASCII letter.

Or, using a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for this; an example in PHP:

```
function mycheck($str)
{
    return strspn($str, '0123456789') != strlen($str);
}

mycheck('12345'); // false
mycheck('123asb'); // true
```

In regex speak, that could also be expressed like this:

```
function mycheck($str)
{
    return !preg_match('/^\d*$/', $str);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also match `123$%/(`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Well, the question said *any* symbol ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, that's indeed unclear.